# Regular expression to get class in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a dynamic array which brings back methods, class and parameters. For example:

```
org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.ignoredBuilder()---begin--->count:1
```

I need a regular expression to get class `org.junit.internal.builders` and `count`

How to do the regex? I have tried this

```
(.*([.]))
```

and i m not sure if this is right.

Comment: Why do you have a capture group around `[.]`?

Comment: What is the idea behind the regex pattern that you tried? It doesn't seem to correlate with what you're attempting. More specifically, your pattern is very general and only focuses on the `.` character, but there are several of those in your input. Why would you anticipate such a pattern to only grab the part you mentioned?

Comment: For one, what you have is a string with '.' as separator, and you want to match anything before the last _two_ '.' in it. Then, you may want to match anything between '--->'  and ':'.

Comment: Something like `^(.+)\.[^.]+\.[^.>]+>([^:]+).+$` should work. It captures anything from the start of the string which is followed by `.<somestring>.<somestring>` and anything after that which is between `>` and `:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your looking for the package name, not the class name.

you might use this regex to capture its parts:

```
^([a-z][^.]+(?:\.[a-z][^.]*)*)\.([A-Z][^.]+)\.([\w]+\([^)]*\))[-]*([^-]+)[->]*([^:]+):([^:]*)
```

*Applied to your string:*

Group 1: org.junit.internal.builders

Group 2: AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder

Group 3: ignoredBuilder()

Group 4: begin

Group 5: count

Group 6: 1